# table view numberOfRowsInSection returning 0

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view which I wish to populate with data stored in parse.com.

However nothing loads in my table view. I've done a few breakpoints and NSLog's and found that my numberOfRowsInSection method is always returning 0.

Here is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

        int num = [_totalDistance count];
        NSLog(@"num = %d", num);
        return [_totalDistance count];

}
```

activityTypeArray is populated from data collected from parse.com in my viewDidLoad method, is it possible this is the problem?

Here is where _totalDistance is populated:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _activityTypeArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    _totalDistance = [NSMutableArray array];
    PFQuery *activityQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Activities"];

    [activityQuery whereKey:@"triathlete" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    [activityQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {

                ;
                NSString *activityType = [object objectForKey:@"activityType"];
                [_activityTypeArray addObject:activityType];

                NSString *totalDistance = [object objectForKey:@"totalDistance"];
                [_totalDistance addObject:totalDistance];
                NSLog(@" total distance %@", _totalDistance);
                int num = [_activityTypeArray count];
                NSLog(@"num = %d", num);
            }

        }
    }];


}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you log the count of `_activityTypeArray` but return the count of `_totalDistance`?

Comment: Debug `_totalDistance` in the `viewDidLoad` method, how can you confirm your data are correctly retrieved from parse ?

Comment: show how you populate '_totalDistance' in viewDidLoad method, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code to reload tableView data. Otherwise your tableView won't know you have data to show.

```
   [activityQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {

                ;
                NSString *activityType = [object objectForKey:@"activityType"];
                [_activityTypeArray addObject:activityType];

                NSString *totalDistance = [object objectForKey:@"totalDistance"];
                [_totalDistance addObject:totalDistance];
                NSLog(@" total distance %@", _totalDistance);
                int num = [_activityTypeArray count];
                NSLog(@"num = %d", num);

                // line added
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }

        }
    }];
```

Comment: This answer is right, but what's the reason to reload the data? Is 'numberOfRowsInSection' executed before 'viewDidLoad'? Are they executed on the same thread?

Comment: @lborgav `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is async method, that mean s `numberOfRowsInSection` will be called before it executes. In other words `numberOfRowsInSection` doesn't know that there is some data.

Answer (score 1):

You are logging another value (_activityTypeArray count) than you are returning as result (_totalDistance count)

So the NSLog statement cannot help

Comment: sorry thats a mistake in my code its i am doing an NSLog for totalDistance. I've edited it now.

Comment: So if numberOfRowsInSection returns 0 I think that's causing your problem. Is it called before _totalDistance is filled by parse.com?

Comment: Yeah, well _totalDistance is populated in viewDidLoad should that be completed before numberOfRowsInSection is called?